# Is a user writing to another user's doc a security concern?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm writing a simple Facebook-like social app that needs to support posts, comments, and likes. Most of the Firestore designs I see keep comments as separate documents. As an experiment, coded the comments and likes as fields of the post document. Seemed to work really well, but now I'm wondering about whether a user updating another user's doc is a security issue? I read up on security rules, but don't understand the nuances. E.g., could I create a security rule that only allows users to create and modify their own comments in another user's post doc?

The benefit I see is that pulling down a single posts pulls down all the comments and likes, but suspect I'm missing something because I don't see this approach used in sample docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering about whether a user updating another user's doc is a security issue?

If you don't want that to happen at all, then yes, it is a security concern.

> could I create a security rule that only allows users to create and modify their own comments in another user's post doc?

Yes, it's possible.

I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) on security rules to better learn how they work, especially the part about [per user rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_authuid).  If you have rules that aren't working the way you expect, please post a new question along with the rules and client code and explain what's happening.

Comment: Thanks @Doug. I will investigate and post if I have issues. As you observed, I was being lazy (on a deadline) and posting what I was proposing to save me from going down a dead-end path. For clarity, what I'm wondering is if whether rules can restrict which portions of a user's document other user's can update?

Comment: Yes, it's a common question that's been discussed on Stack Overflow.